# Jenkins Email template not working

Tags: email, jenkins, jelly

I am trying to customize jenkins email template by adding jelly script. The script is working fine , but i am not getting the colour balls in mail, the balls are greyed out. 
Below is the script. Can anyone please assist what changes needs to be done to the script so that colour balls will appear in jenkins emails.

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define">

<STYLE>
BODY, TABLE, TD, TH, P {
  font-family:Verdana,Helvetica,sans serif;
  font-size:11px;
  color:black;
}
h1 { color:black; }
h2 { color:black; }
h3 { color:black; }
TD.bg1 { color:white; background-color:#0000C0; font-size:120% }
TD.bg2 { color:white; background-color:#4040FF; font-size:110% }
TD.bg3 { color:white; background-color:#8080FF; }
TD.test_passed { color:blue; }
TD.test_failed { color:red; }
TD.console { font-family:Courier New; }
</STYLE>
<BODY>
<j:set var="spc" value="&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;" />


<!-- GENERAL INFO -->

<TABLE>
  <TR><TD align="right">
    <j:choose>
      <j:when test="${build.result=='SUCCESS'}">
        <IMG SRC="${rooturl}static/e59dfe28/images/32x32/blue.gif" />
      </j:when>
      <j:when test="${build.result=='FAILURE'}">
        <IMG SRC="${rooturl}static/e59dfe28/images/32x32/red.gif" />
      </j:when>
      <j:otherwise>
        <IMG SRC="${rooturl}static/e59dfe28/images/32x32/yellow.gif" />
      </j:otherwise>
    </j:choose>
  </TD><TD valign="center"><B style="font-size: 200%;">BUILD ${build.result}</B></TD></TR>
  <TR><TD>Build URL</TD><TD><A href="${rooturl}${build.url}">${rooturl}${build.url}</A></TD></TR>
  <TR><TD>Project:</TD><TD>${project.name}</TD></TR>
  <TR><TD>Date of build:</TD><TD>${it.timestampString}</TD></TR>
  <TR><TD>Build duration:</TD><TD>${build.durationString}</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
<BR/>


<!-- CHANGE SET -->

<j:set var="changeSet" value="${build.changeSet}" />
<j:if test="${changeSet!=null}">
  <j:set var="hadChanges" value="false" />
  <TABLE width="100%">
    <TR><TD class="bg1" colspan="2"><B>CHANGES</B></TD></TR>
    <j:forEach var="cs" items="${changeSet}" varStatus="loop">
      <j:set var="hadChanges" value="true" />
      <j:set var="aUser" value="${cs.hudsonUser}"/>
      <TR>
        <TD colspan="2" class="bg2">${spc}Revision <B>${cs.commitId?:cs.revision?:cs.changeNumber}</B> by
          <B>${aUser!=null?aUser.displayName:cs.author.displayName}: </B>
          <B>(${cs.msgAnnotated})</B>
         </TD>
      </TR>
      <j:forEach var="p" items="${cs.affectedFiles}">
        <TR>
          <TD width="10%">${spc}${p.editType.name}</TD>
          <TD>${p.path}</TD>
        </TR>
      </j:forEach>
    </j:forEach>
    <j:if test="${!hadChanges}">
      <TR><TD colspan="2">No Changes</TD></TR>
    </j:if>
  </TABLE>
<BR/>
</j:if>


<!-- ARTIFACTS -->

<j:set var="artifacts" value="${build.artifacts}" />
<j:if test="${artifacts!=null and artifacts.size()&gt;0}">
  <TABLE width="100%">
    <TR><TD class="bg1"><B>BUILD ARTIFACTS</B></TD></TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>
        <j:forEach var="f" items="${artifacts}">
          <li>
            <a href="${rooturl}${build.url}artifact/${f}">${f}</a>
          </li>
        </j:forEach>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
<BR/>  
</j:if>


<!-- MAVEN ARTIFACTS -->

<j:set var="mbuilds" value="${build.moduleBuilds}" />
<j:if test="${mbuilds!=null}">
  <TABLE width="100%">
      <TR><TD class="bg1"><B>BUILD ARTIFACTS</B></TD></TR>
      <j:forEach var="m" items="${mbuilds}">
        <TR><TD class="bg2"><B>${m.key.displayName}</B></TD></TR>
        <j:forEach var="mvnbld" items="${m.value}">
        <j:set var="artifacts" value="${mvnbld.artifacts}" />
        <j:if test="${artifacts!=null and artifacts.size()&gt;0}">
      <TR>
        <TD>
          <j:forEach var="f" items="${artifacts}">
            <li>
              <a href="${rooturl}${mvnbld.url}artifact/${f}">${f}</a>
            </li>
          </j:forEach>
        </TD>
      </TR>
        </j:if>
        </j:forEach>
      </j:forEach>
  </TABLE>
<BR/>  
</j:if>


<!-- JUnit TEMPLATE -->

<j:set var="junitResultList" value="${it.JUnitTestResult}" />
<j:if test="${junitResultList.isEmpty()!=true}">
  <TABLE width="100%">
    <TR><TD class="bg1" colspan="2"><B>JUnit Tests</B></TD></TR>
    <j:forEach var="junitResult" items="${it.JUnitTestResult}">
      <j:forEach var="packageResult" items="${junitResult.getChildren()}">
        <TR><TD class="bg2" colspan="2"> Name: ${packageResult.getName()} Failed: ${packageResult.getFailCount()} test(s), Passed: ${packageResult.getPassCount()} test(s), Skipped: ${packageResult.getSkipCount()} test(s), Total: ${packageResult.getPassCount()+packageResult.getFailCount()+packageResult.getSkipCount()} test(s)</TD></TR>
        <j:forEach var="failed_test" items="${packageResult.getFailedTests()}">
          <TR bgcolor="white"><TD class="test_failed" colspan="2"><B><li>Failed: ${failed_test.getFullName()} </li></B></TD></TR>
        </j:forEach>
      </j:forEach> 
    </j:forEach>  
  </TABLE>  
<BR/>
</j:if>


<!-- COBERTURA TEMPLATE -->

<j:set var="coberturaAction" value="${it.coberturaAction}" />
<j:if test="${coberturaAction!=null}">
  <j:set var="coberturaResult" value="${coberturaAction.result}" />
  <j:if test="${coberturaResult!=null}">
    <table width="100%"><TD class="bg1" colspan="2"><B>Cobertura Report</B></TD></table>
    <table width="100%"><TD class="bg2" colspan="2"><B>Project Coverage Summary</B></TD></table>
            <table border="1px" class="pane">
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <j:forEach var="metric" items="${coberturaResult.metrics}">
                        <td>${metric.name}</td>
                    </j:forEach>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>${coberturaResult.name}</td>
                    <j:forEach var="metric" items="${coberturaResult.metrics}">
                        <td data="${coberturaResult.getCoverage(metric).percentageFloat}">${coberturaResult.getCoverage(metric).percentage}%
                            (${coberturaResult.getCoverage(metric)})
                        </td>
                    </j:forEach>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <j:if test="${coberturaResult.sourceCodeLevel}">
                <h2>Source</h2>
                <j:choose>
                    <j:when test="${coberturaResult.sourceFileAvailable}">
                        <div style="overflow-x:scroll;">
                            <table class="source">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="3">${coberturaResult.relativeSourcePath}</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                ${coberturaResult.sourceFileContent}

                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </j:when>
                    <j:otherwise>
                        <p>
                            <i>Source code is unavailable</i>
                        </p>
                    </j:otherwise>
                </j:choose>
            </j:if>

            <j:forEach var="element" items="${coberturaResult.childElements}">
                <j:set var="childMetrics" value="${coberturaResult.getChildMetrics(element)}"/>
               <table width="100%"><TD class="bg2" colspan="2">Coverage Breakdown by ${element.displayName}</TD></table>
                <table border="1px" class="pane sortable">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <j:forEach var="metric" items="${childMetrics}">
                            <td>${metric.name}</td>
                        </j:forEach>
                    </tr>
                    <j:forEach var="c" items="${coberturaResult.children}">
                        <j:set var="child" value="${coberturaResult.getChild(c)}"/>
                        <tr>

                            <td>
                                ${child.xmlTransform(child.name)}
                            </td>
                            <j:forEach var="metric" items="${childMetrics}">
                                <j:set var="childResult" value="${child.getCoverage(metric)}"/>
                                <j:choose>
                                    <j:when test="${childResult!=null}">
                                        <td data="${childResult.percentageFloat}">${childResult.percentage}%
                                            (${childResult})
                                        </td>
                                    </j:when>
                                    <j:otherwise>
                                        <td data="101">N/A</td>
                                    </j:otherwise>
                                </j:choose>
                            </j:forEach>
                        </tr>
                    </j:forEach>
                </table>
            </j:forEach>
  </j:if>
<BR/>
</j:if>


<!-- CONSOLE OUTPUT -->

<j:getStatic var="resultFailure" field="FAILURE" className="hudson.model.Result"/>
<j:if test="${build.result==resultFailure}">
<TABLE width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<TR><TD class="bg1"><B>CONSOLE OUTPUT</B></TD></TR>
<j:forEach var="line" items="${build.getLog(100)}"><TR><TD class="console">${line}</TD></TR></j:forEach>
</TABLE>
<BR/>
</j:if>

</BODY>
</j:jelly>
```

Comment: Can anyone assist on this please.

Comment: Can anyone assist on this please.

Answer (score 0):

change the img src to a website address..something like :

img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/master/war/src/main/webapp/images/32x32/green.gif"